# Plotting a column of precision floating point values

Tags: j

I have a sequence of data that I have modified to the following:

```
load 'tables/csv'
load 'graphics/plot'
x =: readcsv 'table_ctl.csv'
dat =: 4 {::|:x 
dat
```

The data in question is pulling the fourth column, that has been transposed of the following sequence of the array. Below is a sample of the first five values for the column.

```
13.5598 13.6815 14.027 14.132 14.0104
```

However upon running:

```
plot dat
```

I get the following error:

```
|option not found: 13.5598: signal
|       signal'option not found: ',j
```

Is this error due to the precision of the floating point values?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting this error as you're passing a list of boxes to plot, and plot is expecting some of these boxes to contain the data to plot, and some other boxes to contain control data. `13.5598` is not a valid option for a plot.

```
   fread 'table_ctl.csv'
a,b,0,1,13.5598
a,b,0,1,13.6815
a,b,0,1,14.027
a,b,0,1,14.132
a,b,0,1,14.0104

   4 {::|: readcsv 'table_ctl.csv'
┌───────┬───────┬──────┬──────┬───────┐
│13.5598│13.6815│14.027│14.132│14.0104│
└───────┴───────┴──────┴──────┴───────┘
```

Probably you were thinking that `{::` automatically unboxes, but it only does this if the path you give it designates a single box. See the top text at [Fetch](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/curlylfcoco#dyadic). The other problem to have is that the contents of these boxes are strings, not floats:

```
   $ > 4 {::|: readcsv 'table_ctl.csv'
5 7
   |."1 > 4 {::|: readcsv 'table_ctl.csv'
8955.31
5186.31
 720.41
 231.41
4010.41
```

So, to plot your numbers: `plot > makenum 4 {::|: readcsv 'table_ctl.csv'` which starts with the list of boxes, then turns each box into a box of a float, then unboxes the list and plots it. `makenum` comes with `readcsv` and is like a smart `". each` in this case, as it would leave non-numeric boxes alone.

There's a bit more to set up, but jd might also work for this:

```
   fread 'table_ctl.cdefs'
 1 label    byte 1
 2 name     varbyte
 3 enabled  boolean
 4 weight   int
 5 score    float
options , LF NO \ 0 iso8601-char

   load 'data/jd'
!!! Jd key: non-commercial use only!
   jdwelcome_jd_ NB. run this sentence for important information

   jdadminnew'temp'
   CSVFOLDER=:'/path/to/csv/directory'
   jd'csvrd table_ctl.csv data'
   jd'info schema'
┌─────┬───────┬───────┬─────┐
│table│column │type   │shape│
├─────┼───────┼───────┼─────┤
│data │label  │byte   │1    │
│data │name   │varbyte│_    │
│data │enabled│boolean│_    │
│data │weight │int    │_    │
│data │score  │float  │_    │
└─────┴───────┴───────┴─────┘
   jd'get data score'
13.5598 13.6815 14.027 14.132 14.0104
```